# Sequelize rename index

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

Sequelize's `QueryInterface` has a [`renameTable`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/query-interface.js~QueryInterface.html#instance-method-renameTable) function. Is there something similar to rename an index?

Answer (score 0):

in sequlize there is no functionality to rename an index.
In erlier stages it even prevented dropping indexes at some occasions. [(refer this](https://github.com/sequelize/cli/issues/332))

Better first drop index and add index with new custom name using a migration.
[To Drop index](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/query-interface.js~QueryInterface.html#instance-method-removeIndex) .
[To add custom index](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/query-interface.js~QueryInterface.html#instance-method-addIndex)